# How to get dynamically loaded HTML to be parsed using Javascript Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using Jquery to dynamically add some HTML into a page.

Now this new HTML code should trigger additional Jquery functions to enable more processing to be done but this new HTML code isnt recognized and thus the additional Jquery functions arent triggered.

How can I get the new HTMl code to be recognized and the additional functions triggered?

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 concerns normally, event handlers and plugins, which are two different things.

---

Part 1: **Event Handlers**

Event handlers are easy, because they act upon events, events behave identically no matter when the element as added.  For this there's [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), `.live()` listens for events on `document` and runs if an event comes from an element that matches the selector, let's take a table row for example:

```
$("tr").click(function() { ... });
```

This would find all **current table rows, when it ran** and bind a `click` event handler to them, the same as [`.bind('click', function)`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).  Then there's [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/), like this:

```
$("tr").live('click', function() { ... });
```

This listens for the `click` event [to bubble up](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) to `document` (this happens automatically, by default) and executes the handler...current and future elements behave the same way here.  This means it works for both.  Then there's [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) which is a local version of `.live()` like this:

```
$("#myTable").delegate('tr', 'click', function() { ... });
```

If you're just adding rows to `#myTable` but not removing/adding the table itself, the same type of listener for bubbling events can sit there, instead of all the way up on `document`, this means the event has to bubble fewer times before reaching the handler you want to execute.

---

Part 2: **Plugins**

Plugins are a bit trickier, because they take elements and do things with them (this is true for *most* plugins). You have two decent options here, either running the plugin when new elements yourself, for example loading via [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or a [shorthand version](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/) would look like this:

```
$.ajax({
  //options...
  success: function(data) {
    //add elements
    $("tr", data).myPlugin();
  }
});
```

This finds new `<tr>` elements, but only in a local [context](http://api.jquery.com/context/) (in the returned HTML) and executes only on those elements.  Alternatively, there's a plugin for this, less efficient, but usually not a noticeable difference on most pages.  [The `.livequery()` plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery/) actively looks for and acts up new elements, the same code would look like this:

```
$("tr").livequery(function() {
  $(this).myPlugin();
});
```

Either of these are valid solutions, just see which fits your needs better.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do. The first thing to look into would be jQuery's .live() methods. You can associate events to matching elements that either exist or will exist in the future. For example, this click method will only bind to existing elements with the class of 'clickme'

```
$('.clickme').bind('click', function() {
  // Bound handler called.
});
```

However, if you bind it using the.live() methods then it will work for existing elements and any new elements that are created:

```
$('.clickme').live('click', function() {
  // Live handler called.
});
```

These examples are taken right off the API page for the live method. Check it out here: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

More details might be helpful but it sounds like Jquery.live() might be what you need. [Jquery.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) binds handlers to elements dynamically.